# Android: closing database before unmounting card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, unmount

I have following problem in my Android app.
Assume I have running service which uses SQLite DB. And user decides to unmount the SDcard (connecting to USB or manually) on which is database file located.
I got notification intent from my broadcast receiver:

```
    IntentFilter MIF = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED);
    MIF.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED);
    MIF.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_EJECT);
    MIF.addDataScheme("file");
    registerReceiver(MediaReceiver,MIF);
```

So I'm able to detect card unmounting. In onReceive block of this receiver I explicitly call database.close() on object I use for querying.
But my app as sill crashing. Not writing it stopped working, just only switching to homescreen, nothing more.

```
    02-14 23:23:30.586: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
    02-14 23:23:31.826: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
    02-14 23:23:33.056: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
    02-14 23:23:34.276: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
    02-14 23:23:35.496: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
     02-14 23:23:36.706: E/ProcessKiller(127): Process cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro (27598) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/Android/data/cz.cuni.mff.drozi.Metro/files/database.db
```

This ends with app crash. But I'm quite sure I have explicitly called close() on the database.

What is the way to close the db so system won't kill my app?

Lot of thanks for all!

Comment: You have three `Intent` actions in your `IntentFilter`. Which one is the main one you respond to in order to close the database? Also, are you sure there isn't another object which is holding an open reference to the database?

Comment: I respond the MEDIA_EJECT intent. I'm sure about closing all instances since I'm using singleton design pattern to connect to the DB.